# Ellipticity of an operator in Gunther's proof of the isometric embedding

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

In Deane Yang's [notes](http://www.deaneyang.com/papers/gunther.pdf) about Gunther's proof of the celebrated isometric embedding theorem,
at the end it is stated that $v$ inherits the regularity of $h$ because the operator $I-Q_0(v,\cdot)$ is **elliptic**.

The relevant formulas are

[image: a passage from Yang's notes]

and $Q_0$ is a smooth linear combination of the $Q_i$'s and $Q_{ij}$'s.

> Now: what is the *meaning* of elliptic in this context? Are we regarding $I-Q_0(v,\cdot)$ as a pseudo-differential operator?
>   (which would bother me a little since usually the symbol of a pseudo-differential operator is assumed to be smooth)
>
> Once the statement is clarified, how can one *check* the ellipticity condition?